# Command to reboot to USB

Tags: linux, windows, macos, usb, bios

I'd like to install linux on a portable USB so I can run it on whatever computer I happen to be on when I'm not at home. However, theres no guarantee that I'll be able to access the computers bios to change the boot order to make sure it will boot from USB first

Is there a command that can be run on both windows and mac osx that will reboot the computer and boot the new session directly from USB, thereby bypassing the need for bios access?

Comment: I think you can do this with bcdedit using the /bootsequence parameter (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731662%28WS.10%29.aspx).  But this may not be an option.  It must be run with administrative privileges.  On most computers, anyone can access the BIOS, and doing what you want would be trivial.  If you can't access the BIOS, I would think administrative privileges would be an even bigger hurdle.